# How to sort a 2d numpy array by the columns with the biggest sum

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, columnsorting

I have a 2D array with shape (35,6004) and I want to sort it based on the sum of the columns. So if I had for example

```
array([[5, 3, 13], 
       [1, 2, 20],
       [6, 2,  6]])
```

I want to sort my array to be like so

```
array([[13, 5, 3], 
       [20, 1, 2],
       [6 , 6, 2]]).
```

I tried finding the index of the column

```
def find_max_col(o):
    t = o.sum(axis=0)
    te = t.tolist()
    return te.index(t.max())
```

then I use the output of that function to sort the array

```
test = array[array[:, find_max_col(array)].argsort()]
```

and do this to check and see if it was successful

```
t1 = test.sum(axis=0)
print(t1)
```

As I understand if I sort according to the column with the biggest sum, I should get an array that shows me the sums of all the columns in a descending form as the output of the above code.

Is my code for checking if worked wrong, did I make a mistake in the sorting or did I not even find the correct index of the column to sort by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if your solution is incorrect, but it is certainly more complicated than necessary:

```py
>>> a = np.array([[5, 3, 13],
                  [1, 2, 20],
                  [6, 2,  6]])

>>> a[:, a.sum(axis=0).argsort()]  # sort columns small-to-large
array([[ 3,  5, 13],
       [ 2,  1, 20],
       [ 2,  6,  6]])

>>> a[:, (a.sum(axis=0)*-1).argsort()]  # multiply sums by -1 to sort large-to-small
array([[13,  5,  3],
       [20,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  6,  2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort the columns by descending order of their sums, do exactly that.

```
idx = array.sum(axis=0).argsort()[::-1]
print(array[:,idx])
```

Your test is correct and the fact that it doesn't produce the right answer means you made a mistake somewhere else. Since you want to sort the columns, `test` should have been at the very least

```
test = array[:,array[:, find_max_col(array)].argsort()]
```

It so happens that `array[:, find_max_col(array)].argsort()` for your exact example produces the right answer, but for the wrong reasons. You are computing the sorted indices of the column of the highest sum, i.e., `array[:,2] == array([13, 20,  6])`, when you're supposed to sort the indices of the column sums in descending order, i.e., `array.sum(axis=0) == array([12,  7, 39])`.